# How to create dynamic xml file in res in android

Tags: android

I want solution of following:

I have create xml file in data/data/com.example.file/files/abc.xml so during running of app how I get this abc.xml in res/layout and should display on screen.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. The XML files used for layouts are pre-compiled to a special binary format in the apk to make inflation faster. It can't be done during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> In general, the XML vocabulary for declaring UI elements closely
>   follows the structure and naming of the classes and methods, where
>   element names correspond to class names and attribute names correspond
>   to methods.

Courtesy goes to @Mike M : You cant create this .**XML files used for layouts are pre-compiled .**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have followed your question- are you trying to attach a child view to the RelativeLayout? If so you want to do something along the lines of:

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, null);
item.addView(child);
```

the RelativeLayout item will be the container for your child view.

Answer (score -1):

**Your question needs to be a bit more specific, but here's a general answer:**

If you are using fragments then you should re-create your fragment and then use:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc, container, false);
```

If you are using activities then you should use:

```
setOnContentView(abc);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Well, the question is about changing the layout.
for the inflater you need that to be returned as your view when you re-create the fragment.